Usage of since with simple present
As per my learning, I kept in mind that since can be used only perfect tenses because since defined by started in the past and continues to the present.However when I saw "how long is it since you were in London" that makes me confused.Because I have mentioned it above how I kept in mind.Why since can be used with present simple and I want to change the sentence as follow,
1.How long is it from when you were in London?
2.How long has it been since you were in London?
Please why since can be used with present simple is correct.

I don't see any examples of the present tense here. The sense of 'you were in London' is 'you visited/spent time in London' - the past tense.

You can't use 'since' with the present tense, because it refers to something that happened in the past! "How long is it since you were in London?" asks how long ago the person's last visit to London was.

If the person is in London now, you would have to ask "How long is it since you arrived in London?"

I don't know how to use since with present simple ,although I can translate "how long is it since you were in london", so I changed the sentence with my own two sentences.What I mean that if the sentence "how long is it........"is correct I can use since with any tenses, is it?For example,"They  already moved to downtown since they got invited from their uncle." and "I am okay since I heard that there is a storm towards us." @Kate Bunting.

Thank you madam, I will keep in mind that how long is it means how long ago. Sorry madam,my reply is late. @Kate Bunting

"Since I heard" and "since they were invited" are not the present simple. As I said, you cannot use 'since' with the present tense.

According as your explanation,so I can use since in these two sentences and  I can use since with any tenses ( I don't mean since + present) , for example, "1.They already moved to downtown since they got invited from their uncle." and "2.I am okay since I heard that there is a storm towards us."  @Kate Bunting

The tenses are fine, the sentences are a bit odd. They have already moved downtown since they were invited by their uncle. I am OK since I heard that there is a storm coming towards us. (Why would an approaching storm make you feel OK?)

@KateBunting the usual rule that's taught regarding usage of perfect tenses with "since" refers to the main clause - I have been living here since my father passed away. I assume this is what the OP is referring to - and there are some tricky exceptions to this rule (eg. I can't stop thinking about her since I saw her).
